# Retrieving dc chart axis generators (from DOM)

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Say, I have loaded a dc bar chart:

[image: chart example.]

I want to retrieve its axes generators. Below, an ax is shown of length 16:

[image]

My first thought would be simply iterating over each j-th ax element `sim.barCharts[i].getElementsByClassName('bar')[j]` after which I calculate its value by subtraction of its attributes `height` and `y`: `value = height - y`.

However, couldn't this also be solved by using the [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) api is some way, or even the [D3](https://github.com/d3/d3) api, since they seem closely related?

The data is already *there*; it was generated by *dc*. It would seem cumbersome to approach this problem from a DOM perspective, without using the facilities of the library who generated the data.

**Context**

I need to retrieve the axis of a chart in order to programmatically dispatch a brush event on it.

```js
  function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    chart.select(".area").attr("d", area);
    chart.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  }
```

The snippet above is the *event handler* of the brush event. As can be seen, the axis generator `xAxis` is needed to create the *brushed* chart values.

Comment: I'm confused. There is only an X axis and a Y axis. But you also mention bars, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you referring to the data itself, which comes from group.all()?

Comment: @Gordon The dc bar chart elements, shown below as `rect` elements, reside in the light-blue marked `chart body` class. I am trying to find the axis generator that generates the data; you call the axis generator on the data, like `chart.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)`. However, I want to do this during runtime, after the charts have alreary been rendered.

Comment: I thought that the x axis generator was just [`chart.xAxis()`](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#xAxis__anchor) but that seems too easy to be what you're looking for. The axis doesn't generate any data, however; it's just another element which is driven by the data. The ticks in the axis are only the same as the data for charts with ordinal scales; they can be quite different from the data for continuous scales.

Comment: @Gordon In my case, I'm working on the runtime environment of a *loaded* page; it's already *rendered* by dc.js. In order to perform a programmatic brush, I want to gain access to the data though the dc.js/D3 API; this is the first challange. Currently, I don't know how to obtain the `chart` object you're referring to, using only the DOM.

Comment: You would read the data using `chart.group().all()` (or directly from the group object, if you have access to it).

Comment: I see. Yes, you need access to the JavaScript runtime environment in order to do anything with dc.js. There isn't any way to get from the chart DOM to the dc.js objects that generated it. If you're not the original author of the page, this might get difficult. But maybe if you poke around in your browser's development environment, you will see some global variables.

Comment: Otherwise you could also try `d3.select('rect.bar').data()`, which will fetch the data which was bound to the bars... That should be the same as the data from the group, maybe with an extra wrapper.

Comment: @Gordon `d3.select('rect.bar').data()` seems promising. :) Does it make a difference if the charts at hand are dc.js charts, when using the D3 API?

Comment: That should work with any D3 charts. Only the format of the data will differ.

Comment: Also, of course, the css selector that you use.